# Magento2: Installing stack on windows subsystem

Tags: magento2.3, ubuntu, windows10

I am unable to access website on my system

I also whitelist domain in hosts file

I followed steps to install magento stack using [installation](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-magento-2-on-ubuntu-18-04/)

Please guide